# Finding the longest string of consecutive positive numbers in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series:

```
series = [0,2, 1, -2, 0, 0, 2, 3 ,1, 7]
```

What is the most time efficient way of finding the length of the longest string of consecutive positive numbers? In this example, it must be 4 (length of [2, 3, 1, 7])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution from `pandas`

```
s=pd.Series(np.sign(np.array(series)))
pd.crosstab(s,s.diff().ne(0).cumsum())
Out[495]: 
col_0  1  2  3  4  5
row_0               
-1     0  0  1  0  0
 0     1  0  0  2  0
 1     0  2  0  0  4

pd.crosstab(s,s.diff().ne(0).cumsum()).max(1)
Out[494]: 
row_0
-1    1
 0    2
 1    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how to make this find the length of the longest string of NEGATIVE numbers as well? I tried changing the `>` to `<` but seems like does not work that way.

Comment: @Saeed check the update , now you have all of them :-)

Answer (score 6):

You could use `itertools.groupby` to group positive numbers, then use `max` to find the longest run of such numbers

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> max((list(g) for k, g in groupby(series, key=lambda i: i > 0)), key=len)
[2, 3, 1, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of *most time efficient* it's going to be hard to beat a simple loop:

```
def maxPositiveRun():
    count = 0
    maxVal = 0
    for n in series:
        if n > 0:
            count +=1
            if count > maxVal:
                maxVal = count
        else:
            count = 0
    return maxVal
```

This assumes by *most time efficient* you mean time for the function to run rather than the time to understand or write the function.